# 8051 microcontroller serial port looping using P0

Tags: port, uart, 8051

Have partial code listed for serial communication between 8051 and external device, but I don't understand the subroutine X00D6. How does the program break out of loop because code sets R7 to FF and then compares to 0??    What does setting P0 to #10 and then setting to 0 do?  How is P0 related to R7?  It appears that R7 is just used a Register in rest of code.

```
    mov r7,#0ffh    ; 00cf   7f ff      
    mov sbuf,a      ; 00d1   f5 99
    acall   X00d6   ; 00d3   11 d6 
    ret             ; 00d5   22        
X00d6:
    mov p0,#10h     ; 00d6   75 80 10   
    mov p0,#0       ; 00d9   75 80 00   
    cjne r7,#0,X00d6    ; 00dc   bf 00 f7   
    ret         ; 00df   22
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that xood6 subroutine will wait until an interrupt line is triggered on the serial transmit line (a data sent on sbuf).  An interrupt will reset the R7 to 0, thereby ending the loop.